# C++ Singleton Implementation - Problems with static

Tags: c++, static, linker, singleton, linker-errors

It has been a while since I've programmed in C++. I was trying to implement a singleton class, but I get an unresolved external symbol. Can you guys point out out to resolve this problem? Thanks in advance!

```
class Singleton
{
    Singleton(){}
    Singleton(const Singleton & o){}
    static Singleton * theInstance;

public:
    static Singleton getInstance()
    {
        if(!theInstance)
            Singleton::theInstance = new Singleton();

        return * theInstance;
    }
};
```

Errors:

> Error  3   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
>
> Error  2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol `"private: static class Singleton * Singleton::theInstance" (?theInstance@Singleton@@0PAV1@A)`

Comment: You probably also want to return `Singleton&` from `getInstance()` since otherwise it will create a copy

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using singleton.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern/1008289#1008289

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have *declared* `Singleton::theInstance`, but you have not *defined* it. Add its definition in some .cpp file:

```cpp
Singleton* Singleton::theInstance;
```

(Also, `Singleton::getInstance` should return a `Singleton&` rather than a `Singleton`.)

Comment: You want to return a reference here rather than a pointer b/c a singleton differs from a typical factory. A factory gives up ownership of the object, while a singleton does not. This explains it well http://www.research.ibm.com/designpatterns/pubs/ph-jun96.txt

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide a definition of `theInstance` *outside* the class declaration, in a C++ implementation file:

```
Singleton *Singleton::theInstance;
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to all the other answers, you could just do away with the private member and use a static-scope function variable:

```
static Singleton getInstance()
{
   static Singleton * theInstance = new Singleton(); // only initialized once!
   return *theInstance;
 }
```

Comment: Why even have a pointer. Just create a static object. Also return a reference.